# How do I change the font color on the login screen?

Tags: login, fonts, desktop-background, colors

In ubuntu, I changed the login wallpaper but the color is so close to white which is also the color of the login user / guest login.
Is there a way I can change the color of the font?

I see posts asking to change font but I don't see if anyone asks about changing the font color.

Can someone give me a hand? *Thanks in advance*

P.S. I have dconf-editor installed.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, that is not possible to do with a single tweak. I have been looking at the source code and nowhere I see an option of font color (see [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/lightdm/trunk/view/head:/data/lightdm.conf) for a list of all possible options). This could be easily added, and you can ask for this feature to the LightDM team joining the mailing list [here](https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/lightdm). I strongly recommend that, as it would also help other users in the future.

Now, here are three possible solutions.

- Use **high-contrast**. This might or might not affect your background image, depending on what it is. Assuming you have `sudo` powers, go to `/etc/lightdm/` and open a file called `lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf` or something related. Then add `high-contrast=true` to the end of the file. Save and restart.
- Change the **theme** of LightDM. This is also on the same file, under `theme-name=...`. If you happen to know available theme names, you can manually replace it there with an alternative one. Yet, it is easier to use a GUI-based manager. For example, try this one:

`sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings`

Then, go to settings, open the LightDM GTK+ Greeter app, and select your preferred theme. There are also plenty of themes online.

- Advanced **Webkit** LightDM: If you are not happy with the above, then this one will surely work. With this one you can create any theme you like using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. If you know these languages, you can achieve what you want. Sadly that goes beyond my knowledge so I cannot help you, but I'm sure there is plenty of help online. Alternatively, try to find a theme online that matches your preferences. There are some amazing themes out there! To install, run this:

`sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter`

To use (according to [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-lightdm-themes/) web) "copy the files located in `/usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/webkit`, and create a new folder there (such as `/usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/mytheme`". Place your created/downloaded theme there.

I hope this helps.